# Clicking elements that are not visible (where there is a slider)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Is there a way to click elements outside line of vision in selenium?
I am trying to click all elements on the slider so I can scrape each page.  However, the job gives me an error with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/TOPBETTA.py", line 1329, in <module>
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '("//*[@class="name"]//span")[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

The Href appears to be the default page as `https://www.topbetta.com.au/sports/` as seen in the image so extracting the Href and navigating to each page individually is not possible.

I was able to scrape this with Winautomation.  Any ideas on how I can do this with Selenium?

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementByxpath("//[@class="name"]//span").style.visibility = "visible";')
```

The above code unfortunately did not help and gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/TOPBETTA.py", line 1329, in <module>
    driver.execute_script('document.getElementByxpath("//*[@class="name"]//span").style.visibility = "visible";')
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 532, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

[image]

```
Code:

try:
    os.remove('vtg121.csv')
except OSError:
    pass

driver.get('https://www.topbetta.com.au/sports/football/')

#SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//*[@id="TopPromotionBetNow"]'))))
#if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TopPromotionBetNow'):
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TopPromotionBetNow').click()

#last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

#while True:

    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    #time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    #new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    #if new_height == last_height:
        #break
    #last_height = new_height

time.sleep(1)

#clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//div[text()="Soccer"][contains(@class, "wn-Classification")]'))))
#clickMe.click()
#time.sleep(0)
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="name"]//span')

indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    time.sleep(0)
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '("//*[@class="name"]//span")[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    clickMe.click()
    time.sleep(0)

    # Team
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,("#js_body-region > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sports-body-region > div.js_event-list-region > div > div.js_events-container.events-container > div > div.js_event-region.event-region > div > a > div > div.team-container.home > div"))))
    langs3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#js_body-region > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sports-body-region > div.js_event-list-region > div > div.js_events-container.events-container > div > div.js_event-region.event-region > div > a > div > div.team-container.home > div")
    langs3_text = []

    for lang in langs3:
        #print(lang.text)

        langs3_text.append(lang.text)
    time.sleep(0)

    # Team ODDS
    langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(" #js_body-region > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sports-body-region > div.js_event-list-region > div > div.js_events-container.events-container > div > div.js_event-region.event-region > div > div > div > div.js_teams-container.market-items > div.head-to-head-item.home > div > div > button.js_price-button.price")

    langs_text = []

    for lang in langs:
        #print(lang.text)
        langs_text.append(lang.text)
    time.sleep(0)

    # Draw odds
    #langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[2]")
    langs1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#js_body-region > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sports-body-region > div.js_event-list-region > div > div.js_events-container.events-container > div > div.js_event-region.event-region > div > a > div > div.team-container.away > div")
    langs1_text = []

    for lang in langs1:
        #print(lang.text)
        langs1_text.append(lang.text)
    time.sleep(0)

    # HREF
    #langs2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='runners']//li[1]")
    url1 = driver.current_url




    print(("NEW LINE BREAK"))
    import sys
    import io


    with open('vtg121.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs_text, langs1_text, langs3_text):
            writer.writerow(row + (url1,))
            print(row + (url1,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution to scrape required pages:

```
url = "https://www.topbetta.com.au/sports/football/"
driver.get(url)

counter = 0
for link in range(len(wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]]'))))):
    wait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mask")))
    link = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]]')))[counter]
    link.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    link = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//a[@href="/sports" and ./div[@class="name"]])[%s]' % str(counter + 1))))
    wait(driver, 15).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mask")))
    link.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="competition-events-module"]')))
    counter += 1
    driver.get(url)
```

Just replace `print(driver.current_url)` with the code you want to apply to each page

Comment: For me it loops through the same link.  Here's my code.  I wonder why that is... HMM https://pastebin.com/bFQQzC0d

Comment: I think I see the problem.  It's printing the  new Href, but not navigating to it.

Comment: I guess you should place more code before `counter += 1`. I mean code that starts from `# Team`

Comment: It's printing the current url https://ibb.co/dJ2ko6 but the page remains the same.  So it's clicking it but the page remains the same so scraped data for one page.  How strange.

Comment: Ohh... this is weird. Ok. give me some time. I'll check

Comment: Well, actually it works correctly - you just need to wait until content resfreshed. You can see it if to set `time.sleep(5)` after `print(driver.current_url)`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now you can see that content is changed after each click

Comment: Awesome. Though it tends to still scrape the same data despite navigating. 
 https://ibb.co/nF3dam  .  I'll see if re-creating job up helps.

Comment: This is because as I've already told you, you should place code you use to scrape data **before `driver.get(url)`** All those line starting from `#Team` put before `driver.get(url)`. Or before `counter += 1`. It doesn't metter.... or instead of `print(driver.current_url)` :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that.  Thanks heaps.  Yeap, done that.  It does everything but write to csv now.  Not sure why that is, but otherwise it works perfectly https://pastebin.com/gvMF2v88

Comment: The not writing to csv is confusing to say the least.  Anyway.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

An element is not clickable when it is not visible in Selenium. You will have to use the scroll buttons to click on all the elements.

Comment: Say you had: clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '("//*[@class="name"]//span")[%s]' % str(index + 1)))) .  How will selenium know which scroll button' element to click to navigate to the element it wants to click.

Comment: The clickMe element is not visible but it does exists. You can search it, determine in which element of the scroll list it resides. With that you can determine which button to use to scroll. After that you can check whether clickMe is displayed. When it is not, scroll further to the element.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that can be done. Hmmm.  The limitation would be it would click the right navigator (if element not found).  Then... eventually you'd have to do if element if element I'm after not found, click right navigator. If right navigator does not exist click left until found or until left click nav does not exist.. I imagine this is possible but quite slow.  HMMMM

Comment: You can get the whole list of items inside the scroll element. And you can determine which elements are visible via the isDisplayed property. In this way you know you have to click the right or left scroll button.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of how that might be done? This might be a viable solution.

Comment: Yes, i'll get back to you for that later. I'm not a Python developer so it will be in c#.